# How to use python itertools module

Tags: python, functional-programming, python-itertools

I have got the following code:

```
import itertools


x = ['Lebron' 'James']
y = ['is', 'the', 'goat']
z = ['is', 'not', 'the', 'goat']
itertools.chain(x, y)
```

And I get the following output: `itertools.chain at 0x104baab50`

What does this output mean? And how can I see the result of the method?

Then the same for the code below:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable([x,y])
```

I get the following output: `itertools.chain at 0x104af7550`

What does this mean? And how can I see the actual result of the method? I'm not quite sure what the difference is between the two methods.

Comment: If you read the documentation https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain you will see that `chain` will return an iterator. You need to iterate it to obtain values. for example `print([*itertools.chain(x, y)])`

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.chain` returns a iterator that will allow you to iterate through the values in a `for` loop, via `__next__`, etc. [like a regular Python iterator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/iterator).

For example:

```
In [3]: import itertools
   ...: x = ['Lebron', 'James']
   ...: y = ['is', 'the', 'goat']
   ...: z = ['is', 'not', 'the', 'goat']

In [4]: for thing in x:
   ...:     print('Thing is', thing)
   ...:
Thing is Lebron
Thing is James

In [5]: for thing in itertools.chain(x, y):
   ...:     print('Thing is', thing)
   ...:
Thing is Lebron
Thing is James
Thing is is
Thing is the
Thing is goat
```

and `from_iterable` takes and iterable (e.g. a list) of iterables (e.g. other lists) and iterates over each in turn:

```
In [8]: for thing in itertools.chain.from_iterable([x, y]):
   ...:     print('Thing is', thing)
   ...:
Thing is Lebron
Thing is James
Thing is is
Thing is the
Thing is goat
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, `chain` is not a function; it's a *type*. Like most types, you get back an instance of that type when you call it. The instance `chain(x,y)` is iterable; it first yields elements from `x`, and when it exhausts `x`, it yields elements from `y`.

`chain.from_iterable` is a class method; it's definition is effectively the same as

```
def from_iterable(itr):
    return chain(*itr)
```

assuming you could use `*` with an arbitrary iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You should see more about the `itertools` module in [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

> What does this output mean? And how can I see the result of the method?

An `itertools.chain` object was returned. This is a generator. You can see the result in such a way for example (iterate through the values using `for` loop):

```
for item in itertools.chain(x, y):
   print(item)
```

or this way (make a list from this iterable):

```
print(list(itertools.chain(x, y)))
```

> itertools.chain(*iterables)

Here you are passing **several** iterables to create a chain from as a function arguments directly:

```
itertools.chain(x, y)
```

> itertools.chain.from_iterable(iterable)

And here you are passing a **single** iterable which contains other iterables to create a chain from:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable([x, y])
```

Comment: `generator` is a specific type, not a class of types that you can iterate over. `chain` returned, well, an instance of `chain`.

Comment: @chepner, thank you very much. You're right. I have edited the answer.